# Access fields using string reference?

Tags: haxe

Can you access fields using a string reference, like in JS?

```js
var o = {hello: "world"};
var ref = "hello";
console.log(o[ref]); //"world"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Reflect.field (o:Dynamic, field:String):Dynamic
```

Returns the value of the field named field on object o.
If o is not an object or has no field named field, the result is null.
If the field is defined as a property, its accessors are ignored. Refer to Reflect.getProperty for a function supporting property accessors.

http://api.haxe.org/Reflect.html#field

Answer (score 4):

Sure you can:

```
var o = {hello: "world"};
var ref = "hello";
trace(Reflect.field(o, ref));
```

Answer (score 4):

To add to the other answers, you can also have an `abstract` with [`@:arrayAccess`](http://haxe.org/manual/types-abstract-array-access.html) methods.

http://try.haxe.org/#79215